# Битрикс и Яндекс касса , почему разные номера заказов

Tags: php, битрикс, яндекс-касса

**На сайте реализована многосайтовость**, два ИМ на которых можно оформлять заказы, подключена яндекс касса. В аккаунте яндекс кассы прописаны ссылки:

```
Check URL https://site1.ru/bitrix/tools/sale_ps_result.php

Aviso URL https://site1.ru/bitrix/tools/sale_ps_result.php

Success URL http://site1.ru/bitrix/tools/sale_ps_success.php

Fail URL http://site1.ru/bitrix/tools/sale_ps_fail.php
```

т.е ссылки от первого сайта, когда клиент делает заказа на втором сайте **site2.ru** то в случае успешной оплаты соответственно от попадает на **site1.ru** , мне **нужно сделать перенаправление на site2.ru** т.е на тот сайт в котором был сделан заказ.

В файле **/bitrix/tools/sale_ps_success.php** я хочу сделать редирект , как мне показалось что это можно сделать **получив ID заказа из URL** который формирует яндекс касса в случае успешной оплаты, в котором есть параметр **orderNumber=273** . Но заметил что номер заказа в яндекс кассе не совпадают с номером заказа на сайте. **К примеру если а ЯК это 273 то на сайте 280** .
И итог того что хочу сделать:
Получить номер заказа из URL, в файле **sale_ps_success.php** проверить  какому сайту пренадлежит заказ и сделать редиррект на нужный сайт https://site2/personal/order/make/?ORDER_ID=".$OrderID

**Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Почему номера заказов разные?**

По совету [Mihanik71][1]  использовать класс Bitrix\Sale\Internals\PaymentTable оказалось верным решением за что ему большое спасибо, ниже пример кода который в файле(sale_ps_success.php) я запилил у себя на сайте:

getlist(array('select' => array('ID','ORDER_ID'),'filter' => array('ID' => $orderNumbder)))->fetch();
    
    $SiteOrder = CSaleOrder::GetByID($shimpentCode['ORDER_ID']); // вытаскиваем свойства заказа, нас интересует поле LID
    
    $SiteID = $SiteOrder['LID']; // id сайта на котором была покупка 
    
    $OrderID = $shimpentCode['ORDER_ID'];
    
    $successUrl = "";
    // простое условие , выбираем куда редиректить покупателя 
    if($SiteID == 's1'){
       $successUrl = "https://site1.ru/personal/order/make/?ORDER_ID=".$OrderID . "&PAY=Y"; // параметр PAY=Y добавил для своих нужд   
    }
    if($SiteID == 's2'){
       $successUrl = "https://site2.ru/personal/order/make/?ORDER_ID=".$OrderID . "&PAY=Y";
    }
    
    
    $successPath = COption::GetOptionString("sale", "sale_ps_success_path", "/");
    
       if(!empty($successUrl)){
          LocalRedirect($successUrl);   
       }
    }


  [1]: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5906/mihanik71

Comment: А в заказе нет свойство, которое бы хранило номер заказа из ЯК? То что номер заказа на сайте не совпадает с платёжной системой — абсолютно нормально

Comment: пока узнал что "В я.кассу передается номер оплаты, а не номер заказа, ну и в ответ соответственно то же самое происходит"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть класс `Bitrix\Sale\Internals\PaymentTable` там по номеру оплаты поле `ID` можно получить номер заказа `ORDER_ID`.

Comment: спасибо, попробую использовать этот класс .

Comment: @Sergey Zaigraev, получилось?

Comment: да, все получилось, добавлю пример кода в вопрос)

Answer (score 3):

Ваше решение не совсем верно с точки зрения нового ядра D7 Битрикс. Нежелательно использовать API старого ядра, когда есть аналоги нового. К тому же было бы неверно использовать    `Bitrix\Sale\Internals\PaymentTable`, потому что нет гарантий, что данное поведение функции сохраниться в дальнейшем, а именно:

> Подпространство Bitrix\Sale\Internals содержит классы для работы с таблицами модуля Интернет-магазин.
>
> Важно! Прямое использование данных классов не рекомендуется и
>   совместимость не гарантируется.

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/sale/internals/

Гораздо лучше использовать доступные публичные статические методы:

```
//Вместо CModule::IncludeModule("sale");
\Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('sale');

//Вместо создания объекта класса Bitrix\Sale\Internals\PaymentTable
$payment = \Bitrix\Sale\Payment::getList(
    array(
       "filter" => array('ID' => $_GET['orderNumber']),
       "select" => array('ORDER_ID')
    )
);

$paymentFields = $payment->fetch();

//Поднимаем объект заказа по id
$order = \Bitrix\Sale\Order::load($paymentFields['ORDER_ID']);

//Получаем поле 'LID'
$SiteID = $order->getField('LID');

//'ID' заказа можно получить и из заказа тоже, например: $OrderID = $order->getId()
$OrderID = $paymentFields['ORDER_ID'];

$successUrl = "";
// простое условие , выбираем куда редиректить покупателя 
if($SiteID == 's1')
{
    $successUrl = "https://site1.ru/personal/order/make/?ORDER_ID=".$OrderID . "&PAY=Y"; // параметр PAY=Y добавил для своих нужд   
}
if($SiteID == 's2')
{
    $successUrl = "https://site2.ru/personal/order/make/?ORDER_ID=".$OrderID . "&PAY=Y";
}

if(!empty($successUrl))
{
  LocalRedirect($successUrl);   
}
```

Можно еще и `$_GET['orderNumber']` через API получать, но это уже так, легкое ООП извращение:

```
$request = \Bitrix\Main\Context::getCurrent()->getRequest();
$request->get("orderNumber");
```